# Why does vector.push_back(System::Byte) not compile any more in VC++ 14.29 (C++/CLI)

Tags: stl, c++-cli

I have the following code that used to compile and work fine:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> marshal_as(cli::array<System::Byte>^ const& from) 
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> result;
    result.reserve(from->Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < from->Length; i++)
    {
        result.push_back(from[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

After updating VisualStudio to version 16.10 - which updates the C++ compiler to version 14.29 - the code produces an error:

> error C2664: 'void std::vector<unsigned
> char,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(const _Ty &)': cannot convert
> argument 1 from 'unsigned char' to 'const _Ty &'
> with
> [
> _Ty=unsigned char
> ]
>
> message : An object from the gc heap (element of a managed array) cannot be converted to a native reference
>
> message : see
> declaration of 'std::vector<unsigned
> char,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back'
> with
> [
> _Ty=unsigned char
> ]

Changing the code in the loop body to

```
    unsigned char b = from[i];
    result.push_back(b);
```

fixes the problem.

I would like to understand the cause of this error. Is this somehow related to a change due to the C++ 20 standard?

Comment: You can probably do `result.push_back((unsigned char)from[i]);` as well.

Comment: @Frank No, this produces the same error message

Comment: Had this been a C++ question: `std::vector<unsigned char> result(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(from.data()), std::next(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(from.data()), from.size()));` - but it's not, so I'll remove the C++ tag.

Comment: @KlausGütter Weird, I just updated my visual studio to 16.10 to test this, and  `result.push_back((unsigned char)from[i]);` definitely makes the problem go away on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this somehow related to a change due to the C++ 20 standard?

No. While `std::vector<>::push()` has subtly changed in C++20, it's not a change that materially affects what's going on here, the issue is definitely clr-specific.

> I would like to understand the cause of this error.

This is almost certainly (see below) an error that was always present in your code, but was not being reported by previous versions of the C++/CLI compiler.

Consider the following function:

```
void foo(const int& v) {
  int* ptr = &v;
  // store ptr somewhere, long-term.
}
```

It's obvious that invoking `foo()` with a reference to a gc-backed `int` would be a recipe for disaster. Yet that's exactly what `result.push_back(from[i]);` does.

Your code "works" because `push_back()` happens to do nothing with its parameter that causes an issue. However, the compiler is *not supposed to know that*.

**N.B.** I say almost certainly because I'm having a heck of a time tracking down the call signature for `cli::array<T>::operator[](std::size_t) const`. It's not impossible that it used to return a `T` and now returns `const T%`.

Comment: Indeed, `operator[](array<unsigned char>^, int) const` returns `unsigned char%`

Comment: @KlausGütter, right, now remaining question is: Did that change?

Comment: checked with VS 16.9.2: `operator[](array<unsigned char>^, int) const` did not change. So the behaviour change seems indeed be in the compiler.